# Create tabs at runtime at the same time as you create the menuitems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drop-down-menu

Im trying to add another tab to the menuitem im creating right now at the same time. In my xaml, the extended tab to the Projects menu item would be Delete. Heres sort of the way id like it:

```
| Projects | > | Project1 |
------------   -----------
               | Project2 | > | Delete |
               ------------   ----------
```

The code underneath is functional but I wasnt able to figure out how to add the delete tab along with each project.

At runtime im creating a menuitem like this:

```
foreach (ViewModels.FloorAssignment_VM ap in projectList)
{
    MenuItem pmi = new MenuItem();
    string projectName = ap.Project_Name;
    projectName = projectName.Replace('_', ' ');
    pmi.Header = projectName;
    pmi.Tag = ap.ProjectKey;
    pmi.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(pmi_Click);
    pmi.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("MenuItemStyleBlue");
    ProjectsMenuItem.Items.Add(pmi);

}
```

and heres my xaml

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="GroupContextMenu" Opened="GroupContextMenu_Opened" Style="{DynamicResource ContextMenuStyleBlue}">
            <MenuItem Name="ProjectsMenuItem" Header="Projects">
                <MenuItem Name="ProjectDeletionMenuItem" Header="Delete"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Name="PropertiesMenuItem" Header="Properties" Click="Properties_Click" />
            <MenuItem Name="ConflictsMenuItem" Header="Conflicts"  />
        </ContextMenu>
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be creating MenuItem objects by hand. If you use data-binding and the HierarchialDataTemplate, you can add / remove items willy-nilly and the UI will automatically update (assuming you are using a collection that is observable such as ObservableCollection.

Your ObservableCollection should not contain MenuItems obviously, but rather your own class that defines the properties you need. From your example, I'd say this class should just contain a string label and an object project key. The rest of the stuff should be via data-binding in your MenuItem template.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you want for each MenuItem in subMenu "Project" to have it's own submenu with "Delete" item, in result having xaml like that:

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Name="GroupContextMenu" Opened="GroupContextMenu_Opened" Style="{DynamicResource ContextMenuStyleBlue}">
        <MenuItem Name="ProjectsMenuItem" Header="Projects">
            <MenuItem Header="Project 1" Tag="1" Click="pmi_Click">
                 <MenuItem Header="Delete" Tag="1" Click="del_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Project 2" Tag="2" Click="pmi_Click">
                 <MenuItem Header="Delete" Tag="2" Click="del_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>                
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Name="PropertiesMenuItem" Header="Properties" Click="Properties_Click" />
        <MenuItem Name="ConflictsMenuItem" Header="Conflicts"  />
    </ContextMenu>
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```

To achieve that through code you can change your generator like that:

```
foreach (ViewModels.FloorAssignment_VM ap in projectList)
{
    MenuItem pmi = new MenuItem();
    string projectName = ap.Project_Name;
    projectName = projectName.Replace('_', ' ');
    pmi.Header = projectName;
    pmi.Tag = ap.ProjectKey;
    pmi.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(pmi_Click);
    pmi.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("MenuItemStyleBlue");
    MenuItem del = new MenuItem();
    del.Header = "Delete";
    del.Tag = ap.ProjectKey;
    del.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(del_Click);
    pmi.Items.Add(del);
    ProjectsMenuItem.Items.Add(pmi);
}
```

However, if you don't need any fine tuning for Menu (e.g. custom placed separators), you should also look on HierarchicalDataTemplate to create your desired menu through binding to ViewModel. 
Also, FindResource - is code version of StaticResource extension, if you want to get DynamicResource, you should do it this way:

```
pmi.SetResourceReference(MenuItem.StyleProperty, "MenuItemStyleBlue");
```